# Get distance between multipatch features in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, distance, 3d, arcscene

I've created 2 multipatch feature classes in ArcGIS, which represent the outer wall of two pipe systems. Now I want to check the smallest 3D distance between all features in the 2 feature classes. I was trying to use Near 3D, but that results in a NEAR_DIST of zero.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Near 3D help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/near-3d.htm) your **NEAR_DIST** field should be 2D distance, which would be zero if the features are overlapping.  You need the **NEAR_DIST3** field.  Also, you need to ensure that the multipatches have z values.